# Add class if element is followed by another

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a class to my 'a.tab' if they are followed by 'ul.subnav'...

```
<ul>

  <li><a class ="tab" href="">Nav 1</a></li>
  <li>
    <a class ="tab" href="">Nav 2</a>
    <ul class="subnav">
       <li><a href="">SubNav 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="">SubNav 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="">SubNav 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a class ="tab" href="">Nav 3</a></li>

</ul>
```

And I have this query code:

```
if($("ul li a.tab").is().next("ul.subnav"){
   $(this).addClass("drop");
}
```

But is not working.

Please, help?

Thanks!!

Comment: There is no `addClass` function in javascript. you probably want `$(this).addClass()`.

Comment: Yes, that was my bad typing, I corrected it, but the script is still not working.

Comment: there is a `)` missing at the end of your if condition; did you look in your debug console?

Comment: Yes, another typo when writing the code here... still doesn't work the script like that... roasted solution works perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery `.filter()` method:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9XPuM/)

```
$("ul li a.tab").filter(function(){
    return $(this).next('ul.subnav').length
}).addClass('drop');
```

Or use next sibling selector:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9XPuM/7/)

```
$(function () {
    $("ul li a.tab + ul.subnav").prev().addClass('drop');
});
```

Comment: What means not working because works in jsfiddle so obviously you are doing something wrong